# sinon - how to check if a value is in an array?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, sinon

I know that i can check a specific value in a specific index, for example - to check for the value at index 0:

```
sinon.assert.match(myArr[0], someValue)
```

But how do i check if `someValue` is anywhere in `myArr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you could do it if you don't want to create a loop that iterates through each element.

```
 myArr.includes(someValue);
```

I haven't tried it with sinon, but see if this works:

```
assert.equals(myArr.includes(someValue), true);
// or
assert(myArr.includes(someValue));
```

Comment: Oh right, i didn't think about that!
But it doesn't work if `someValue` is an object.. do you know how to make it work?

Comment: @Gambit2007 well in that case you can use `myArray.find(predicate)` where `predicate` defines your criteria. When you say it doesn't work when `someValue` is an object that implies you want to equate objects in a specific way where as `includes` equates 
objects by identity.

Comment: @Gambit2007 well objects have reference identity (they are just fancy pointers). Given `eq = (a, b) => a === b`, and `a = {}` and `b = {}`, `eq(a, b)` is `false` but for `a = {}` and `b = a` `eq(a, b)` is `true` because `a` and `b` refer to the same object

Comment: Ohhh ok, so `myArr.includes()` would only work if the same object is referenced?